# How to properly detach an Entity from Hibernate EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to test out JPA a little and so I created the following class `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    protected User() {
    }

    public User(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Now I got the following test-class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AssignmentTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByName_thenReturnUser() {
        //given
        User user = new User("Firstname", "Lastname");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();

        //when
        User found = userRepository.findUsersByLastname(user.getLastname()).get(0);

        entityManager.detach(user);
        user.setLastname("Boohoo");

        //then
        assertThat(found.getLastname())
            .isEqualTo("Lastname");
    }
}
```

Now I'd like the entityManager to stop changing the value of my Entity. I read a few posts that told to use `detach`, `remove` or `clear` - none of it worked out. I still get (on test run):

```
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<"[Lastname]"> but was:<"[Boohoo]">
```

I tried to see into the statements Hibernate is executing, but I cannot see that hibernate would execute an `update`-statement.

What did I do wrong on that?

Comment: Is the LastName actually persisted to the database or just changed in found?

Comment: I thought it is persisted from the moment I call `persist(user)` and until I `detach(user)`?

Comment: What I am asking you to do is to actually look in your database and see what the value for the lastname column is.  Is it LastName or Boohoo?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `user` and `found` are pointing to *the same object*.

First, you call persist on `user`, meaning that the object that `user` references becomes a managed entity. You then call:

```
User found = userRepository.findUsersByLastname(user.getLastname()).get(0);
```

and, since the `User` that matches the query criteria is already present in the persistence context, a reference to that (previously persisted) object is returned.

Calling `entityManager.detach(user)` *does* detach the entity referenced by `user`. It's just that `found` references that very same object at this point.